# Covariance Matrix of HIERARCHICAL MULTITASK GAUSSIAN PROCESS

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gaussian-process, hierarchical-bayesian, multitask-learning

I'm currently trying to develop a **Gaussian Process** to predict **different levels of different individuals over time**.

So it is a **Time Regression Problem** in which we have **multiple tasks, but also multiple individuals**... In other words, the shape of my data is **[nb_individuals, nb_time_steps, nb_levels]** and i try to predict accurately what will be those levels in the future.

Note that for a single person, the time of the samples are the same for all the levels (that can be irregularly separated)

**Questions**

- 1) **if we assume that the levels from different individuals are just different realizations of the same Multitask Gaussian Process**, how to we train our model ? I mean, we want to have the **same covariance matrix between all the individuals**, but the levels are changing from one person to the other, so we want to have **different mean functions**... Am i right ? At the end, it's not independent Gaussian processes because we don't want to have several covariance matrices, but it's not like a multiperson Gaussian process because they share their covariance matrix.
- 2) Now we assume that **each individual has his own behavior**, to see the **correlation between different individuals**. Is it related to **Hierarchical Gaussian Processes** ? Does it means now that the covariance matrix is a matrix whose shape is [nb_individuals * nb_time_steps * nb_levels , nb_individuals * nb_time_steps * nb_levels]

I have **already implemented a Multitask  Gaussian Process** (it means that my covariance matrix is the Kronecker product of a matrix of time covariance and a matrix of levels covariance) for a single person, so i'm considering only the individual level... and i would like to **include the signal that come from the population level** (see Question 2). It would be great to see how an individual differs from the group !

I'm using **Python** to develop my algorithms and it seems really complicated to find a code with Hierarchical GP, if it is the right thing to apply, and do you know a library i can use ? I've seen a package in Matlab but none in Python.

It's quite strange that training a model by using multiple repetitions of the same Gaussian Process seems so hard... Am i doing it wrong ? Should i look at Multilevel GP, Hierarchical GP or Mixture of GP ?

Thank you so much for your help, it would help me a lot !